# how do I make my nether portal work in minecraft pocket edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Where do I light my nether portal on Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.10.5?

Answer (score 3):

You don't: Nether Portals [have not been implemented in Pocket edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_version_history#A0.10.5). In its place, Pocket Edition has [Nether Reactors](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Reactor) as the means to obtain various nether related blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You make a cross with 5 cobble stone, like a plus sign, then put four gold blocks in the corners, then put an nether reactor core in the middle of the square, then make another cobblestone plus sign on top of nether reactor core, then put 4 Cobble stone on the gold

Answer (score -1):

You can't do the nether on MCPE; it only works with PC, Xbox and Playstation editions.

Answer (score -2):

To get the nether you have to have 4 gold blocks, a nether reactor-core and some cobblestone and make a shrine type thing. Look up how to build it on YouTube

Comment: Telling someone to go look on Youtube isn't very helpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zC1KtTMRuHw

Comment: Sorry I didn't post the link in my first comment